# Looping through database to get details, then send email with said values

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, email

I am bringing in brochures selected by visitors, and they can select multiple brochures. After three days they are meant to get an email reminding them of the brochures they have chosen.

Here is what I have so far:

```
$time_query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE time < (now() - INTERVAL 1 minute)"; //" //GROUP BY time does group them into an array... well.. it doesnt display duplicate timestamps, so assume it saves it to an array'";

    $time_query_result = mysql_query($time_query, $db) or 

    die("Could not execute sql: $time_query"); 

        $users = array();

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($time_query_result)) {

            if (!array_key_exists($users[$row["id"]], $users)) {

                $users[$row["id"]] = array('email' => $row["email"], 'brochures' => array());
                $users[$row["id"]]["brochures"] = array('b' => $row["brochures"], 't' => $row["time"]);

            }

        }

        foreach ($users as $user) {

            $text = '<html><body><p>Brochure reminder</p>';
              $i = 0;

            foreach ($user["brochures"] as $brochure) {

                $text .= 'Brochures:<br />'.$i++ . $row["b"];
            }

            $text .= '</body></html>';
            mail($user["email"], $subject, $text, $headers);
        }
```

I am getting numbers through the emails instead of brochure names, and I think its something to do with the array_key_exists fuinction.

Each time a user selects a brochure, it creates its own row in the DB, and the idea was to pull in the multiple brochures a user selected at a time (by the time column), as many users can select brochures over a time period.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your 'while' loop, you're creating a new 'brochures' element in your 'users' array, when I think you're wanting to append to it.

```
if (!array_key_exists($row["id"], $users)) {
    $users[$row["id"]] = array('email' => $row["email"], 'brochures' => array());
}
$users[$row["id"]]["brochures"][] = array('b' => $row["brochures"], 't' => $row["time"]);
```

then in your 'foreach', you will want to use the brochure variable:

```
foreach ($user["brochures"] as $brochure) {
    $text .= 'Brochures:<br />'.$i++ . $brochure["b"];
}
```

Comment: That has changed something - now the email returns different numbers for each email, but I am getting an email for each brochure still, as opposed to one email with all selected brochures inside :( thanks though

Comment: I just also noticed, that in your while loop, you're creating a new array for brochures each time rather than appending to it.

Comment: Just noticed as well that you you were only adding to the brochures array if the brochures array was not already there. just moved that bit of code out of the 'if'.

Comment: Yes tthat has worked! Thanks so much. Well... it is now correctly displaying the names of the selected brochures etc... from the array. The only problem now is that its not gathering all brochures in one email and sending it once... its sending an email for each brochure selected.. any thoughts?

Comment: Oh, that's because you're using array_key_exists with an element from the array rather than a key, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much, that has sorted it! Really pleased. Its helkped me understand the entire usage of arrays etc... much more. Thankyouuu

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help. Don't forget to make the answer as the solution to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your current code builds an array of users containing another array with the index 'brochures'. This array will always contain tow values.

```
{
    'b' => $row["brochures"]
    't' => $row["time"])
}
```

Regarding this fact the following statements doesn't make sense:

```
foreach ($user["brochures"] as $brochure) {

}
```

All you do is iterate over the two values with the index 'b' and 't'. If you want to iterate over a collection of brochures you need to adapt your code.

---

On the other hand you have a few important mistakes:

```
foreach ($user["brochures"] as $brochure) {
    $text .= 'Brochures:<br />'.$i++ . $row["b"];
}
```

Why use a foreach if you don't even use the $brochure variable?

```
$text .= 'Brochures:<br />'.$i++ . $row["b"];
```

$row contains the last row, which is definitively not what you wanted. In fact, $row is out of scope, in a serious programming language you would see this.

```
$row["id"]
```

You use this about three times. So why not store it in a variable $id? Accessing arrays with indexes is a more expensive operation than simply accessing a variable.

In general I strongly encourage you to switch to an object oriented approach so you get rid of these ugly array in array in array solution...